# How to deal with optional field input in React controlled forms

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

Let's say I have a form with 3 fields: `firstName`, `middleName`, `lastName`. The fields `firstName` and `lastName` are mandatory, but `middleName` is optional. So, when someone completes the form without writing his middle name, the object that is produced by the form is something like

```
{
  firstName: "John",
  middleName: "",
  lastName: "Doe",
}
```

but I would like to get something like

```
{
  firstName: "John",
  middleName: undefined,
  lastName: "Doe",
}
```

Of course I could manually clean the resulting object, and convert `""` to `undefined`, but I wonder if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom logic to handle this:

```
const initialValues = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    middleName: ""
}
// Set use state
const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);

const handleMiddleNameInputChange = (event) => {
    event.persist();
    if(middleName === ""){
        setValue((values)=>({
            ...values,
            middleName: "undefined"
        }));
    }else{
        setValues((values) => ({
            ...values,
            middleName: event.target.value,
        }));
    }
};
```